# Juggling Algorithm time complexity

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Time Complexity of Juggling algorithm for array rotation(Suppose 'd' times) is computed as O(n), where n is the size of the array. But for any number of rotation(i.e. for any value of 'd'), the algorithm runs exactly for n times. So, shouldn't the time complexity of the algorithm be "Theta(n)" ? It always loops for n times in any case.If not, can anyone provide a test case where it doesn't run for n times?

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you ask, but if we look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-rotation/ we see that it is described as O(n) time but if we want to rotate zero steps it could be done in O(1) time, so it doesn't always take n times - i.e. Theta(n) would be wrong; but O(n) is correct.

Comment: Ok, got it. But if d > 0, then it always runs 'n' times. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but, if you run the algorithm provided on geeksForgeeks, it runs exactly n times, even for d = 0. Can you please look into this? If you find a test case in which it doesn't run for 'n' times, kindly provide it.